# Html/body tags not covering the entire content in an asp.net site

Tags: html, css, asp.net

This is going to be my first question here. I always manage to either find an answer somewhere, or find out a solution, but this is the most frustrating problem I've ever seen, and I can't find anyone else talking about it.

I'm working on a site that was made in asp.net. The problem is, the body tag simply refuses to cover the entire screen no matter what. The html was recently rewritten, but the same thing still happens. I would consider it being an asp problem, but I know nothing about it.

The asp page itself doesn't have anything relevant besides the html, no fixed heights or anything anywhere.

The code outside it is this, in case this is something caused here or can be fixed here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>

    <FRAMESET Rows="*,0" BORDER="0" FRAMEBORDER="NO">

    <FRAME SRC="../../part/page.aspx" Name="name" Scrolling="auto">
    <FRAME SRC="spacer.aspx" Name="name" Scrolling="no">


    </FRAMESET>
</html>
```

What actually happens: The body covers a fixed portion of the screen. It completely ignores any attempts to make it 100%, and the few things I got to work to make it 100% only worked sometimes, and then the html tag was 100% and the body wasn't, or body and html were but the wrapper div (covering the whole content) then suddenly wasn't.

This is some of the code I tried to use:

```
html {
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; } 

body, html, #wrapper, #menu {
    position: relative; }

body, #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }

#content:after, #wrapper:after  {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both; }
```

I tried 100vh too, it didn't work any better.

Any ideas? I'm completely lost here, nothing works, and when it does, it stops working for no reason. The content has nothing to do with it, it will act like this no matter what the content is. I have no idea why but position: relative worked once, and I thought the problem was solved, but now it doesn't anymore.

One thing I noticed is that some of these things (like min-height 100% on body), fixes the problem "a bit". So say the body and html are at a 200px height, then I add min-height:100%, it goes up to 400px. But 400px still doesn't cover the entire screen. Then I add position: relative and it adds up a bit more. This might be what made me think it was "fixed", but isn't.

Also, this is not browser specific, it does this on both chrome or ff.

This would not be a problem if I didn't have a sidebar that needs to use 100% height with a background, and it gets cut off while the content inside goes on normally. At this point I'm considering leaving the page ugly and having a fixed large min-height, because its the only thing that has truly worked so far.

Edit: I've now noticed that sometimes the sidebar covers the whole page, even if the body/html are getting cut half way into the page.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try to determine how big the `FRAME` is. My guess is, it's not 100%. _Frames?!_ Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: I'm only working on the css/html. The site is over 15 years old from what I can gather. Nothing I can do about that.

Would setting height 100% in the frames work perhaps?

Comment: Worth a shot. Put it on the `frameset` and the `frame` tags.